# Como chamar popover no lugar no lugar de uma infowindow?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Estou com uma situação no maps em que tenho diversos marcadores no mapa e cada um deles com uma identificação diferente. Consigo usar a infowindow normalmente para exibir todos os dados relativos aquele marcador. Porém, precisarei implementar um html mais avançado e irei usar o "popover" do bootstrap ao invés da infoviewer. Minha função de clique no marcador segue abaixo

```
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
    /// implementação
    var conteúdo = "<p>conteúdo qualquer</p>";
    infoWindow.setContent(iwContent);
    infoWindow.open(map, this);
   })
```

Como posso chamar um popover para esse marcador (sem confundir os dados dele com os de outros marcadores) ao invés de chamar a infowindow padrão do maps?

Comment: O popover a que se refere será a modal de boostrap?

Comment: O modal do bootstrap escurece a tela por trás e aparece no meio da tela. Já o popover do bootstrap aparece como um balãozinho, onde posso jogar html. É esse balãozinho que quero usar.

Comment: Ha ok.. Percebi, não conhecia

Comment: @DiChrist, você está com dificuldades de utilizar o Popover? Ou sua questão é mais de Design mesmo?

Comment: é usar o popover Andrew, não consigo chamar o popover para o marcador que eu clico

Comment: já tentou?  `var options = { content: 'conteúdo aqui' };  $('#exemplo').popover(options)`;

Comment: [Veja se isso](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10545768/google-map-in-twitter-bootstrap-popver) te ajuda. Ou [esse exemplo no jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/14rnvdzm/).

Comment: que elemento com id é esse ('exemplo')?